# Why can't I call slice() on ENV?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If ENV[] is a hash-like object (per http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/ENV.html) why can't I call .slice(*keys) on it? What is the best way for extracting specific key-value pairs from the Environment into another Hash?

Comment: Being hash-like does not mean it is a hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no slice method on a hash. If you want the keys to the ENV you can call:

```
ENV.keys
```

If you want to copy over a value to a new hash you can call:

```
# ex. Copying over the PATH variable from ENV hash.
hash = {}
hash[:path] = ENV["PATH"]
```

For more info on ruby hashes read the docs for hash and enumerable:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html

Comment: Ah. I was confusing the Ruby Hash with a Rails Hash. Rails adds a .slice(*keys) method to its Hash object, but that doesn't apply to ENV. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of keys for the env variables you want to grab:

```
keys_wanted = %w{key1 key2 etc}
```

---

### Using `values_at`, `zip` and `Hash[]`

You can use `values_at` to get an array of the corresponding values:

```
values_wanted = ENV.values_at(*keys_wanted)
```

Which you could then zip up with the keys into a new hash:

```
Hash[keys_wanted.zip(values_wanted)]
```

---

### Using `select`

This is a little more straightforward but has the downside of having to search through the keys_wanted array for each key.

```
ENV.select {|key| keys_wanted.include? key }
```

---

#### Documentation:

- [Hash.values_at](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/values_at)
- [Array.zip](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip)
- [Hash[] constructor](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/%5B%5D/class)
- [Hash.select](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/select)
- [Array.include?](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is helpful in answering the second part of my question, whereas @demondeac11 also answered my question about why slice doesn't work.